# Nonlinear quadratic Inequality

Tags: multivariable-calculus, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, quadratic-forms, nonlinear-system

Let $f:\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be a smooth function. Then
$$k_1(x-y)^T(x-y) \le (f(x)-f(y))^T(f(x)-f(y)) \le k_2(x-y)^T(x-y)$$ 
for any $x,y \in \Omega$, where $k_2>k_1$ are two arbitrary constants.($T$ denotes transpose operator).

I am wondering if this inequality has been used somewhere in the literature. Also I am not sure if this condition is only satisfied when $f(\cdot)$ is linear, i.e. f(x)=Ax with $A \in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that $0<k_1 \leq k_2$ (else you have triviality), $f$ satisfying this condition is [bi-Lipschitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity#Definitions) (equivalence of Wikipedia's definition and your inequality becomes apparent if you scale $f$). Such a map has to be continuous (obviously, by the upper bound), and the lower bound forces injectivity.